# Do I need to close the DbConnection manually when using ambient transactions with EF Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, transactionscope

EF Core 2.1 introduced support for ambient transactions. The [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#using-systemtransactions) creates a new `SqlConnection`, manually opens it and passes it to the `DbContext`:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(
    TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
    new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
{
    var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();

    try
    {
        // Run raw ADO.NET command in the transaction
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM dbo.Blogs";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Run an EF Core command in the transaction
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(connection)
            .Options;

        using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
        {
            context.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnet" });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        // Commit transaction if all commands succeed, transaction will auto-rollback
        // when disposed if either commands fails
        scope.Complete();
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        // TODO: Handle failure
    }
}
```

There is no call to `connection.Close()` though.

Is this part just missing in the sample or is the connection closed automatically somehow when the `TransactionScope` or the `DbContext` are disposed?

Edit: The call to Close/Dispose *was* missing. I filed a pull request and the docs are updated now.

Comment: You'll have to test it, eg with SQL Server Profiler - a connection has to be created *inside* a transaction for it to autoenlist. Otherwise you'd have to explicitly call `Enlist()`. A connection can't close before the transaction itself commits, otherwise commiting/rolling back would be impossible. **Maybe** some magic code takes care of actually closing the connection when the TransactionScope goes out of scope. Maybes aren't good for data access code though

Comment: That's why I came here to ask.

Comment: I'd avoid such code. Even if that magic code exists, you'd have to ensure that this code is *always* called inside a `TransactionScope` to enable the magic. If some other developer or even you forgets it you'll start leaking connections.

Comment: Use need to call `context.Database.OpenConnection()` and `context.Database.CloseConnection()` in `using` block

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The behavior seems to be unrelated to ambient transactions, but the answer of the question *who owns the `DbConnection` passed to a `DbContext`*.

EF6 `DbContext` constructor accepting `DbConnection` has `bool contextOwnsConnection` parameter for explicitly specifying that.

But how about EF Core? There is no such parameter on `UseXyz` methods accepting `DbConnection`.

The rule seems to be the as follows, taken from [`UseSqlServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbcontextoptionsextensions.usesqlserver?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions_UseSqlServer__1_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptionsBuilder___0__System_Data_Common_DbConnection_System_Action_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_SqlServerDbContextOptionsBuilder__) method `connection` parameter documentation:

> If the connection is in the open state then EF will not open or close the connection. If the connection is in the closed state then EF will open and close the connection as needed.

Which I read *"If the passed connection is not opened, EF Core will take the ownership, otherwise the ownership is left to the caller"*.

Since the example calls `connection.Open();` before `UseSqlServer(connection)`, I would assume you are responsible for closing/disposing it, so I would consider the example being incorrect.

Comment: Looking at the examples I come to the same conclusion. Pretty sloppy :(

Answer (score 0):

For safeside use using so that the connection is disposed.

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't use using because my code is more complex than the sample. My question was more about whether I am responsible for closing the connection or not and not about the how (and if yes, why the code is missing from the sample in the documentation).

Comment: Sorry, my answer was not on to the point.  Regarding the sample, connection is used instanciated and used in DbContext and Command. if dbcontext example, the db creates and closes connection. However, the sample above, that's not the case. The connection has to be closed manually. Even garbage collector dispose the connection object, I can not 100% sure the connection with the database is properly terminated. Database might reject addtional connection after reading limit (depends on type of database). As per your question, I think closing connection is missing.

Comment: Please check this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/172c97e7-4870-4498-aec2-c748cdb4b1d9/what-happens-to-a-closed-connection-in-a-transactionscope-be-it-reusable-by-other-threads?forum=adodotnetdataproviders