# When does EF Core DBContext dispose Sql Connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, sqlconnection

When using classic ADO.NET we typically close the SQL connection as soon as we are done executing the SQL command, so the connection is closed and returned back to the pool.

Something like:

```
public Order[] GetActiveOrders()
{
        var orders = new List<Orders>();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "Select * FROM ORDERS WHERE Status = 'Active'";
                cmd.Connection.Open();

                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    //populate orders
                }
            }
        }
        
        // SQL connection is closed here and returned back to connection pool
        
        return orders;
}
```

In ASP.NET Core using EF Core, we typically inject the `DbContext` into constructor using DI framework

```
      public class OrderService:IDisposable
      {
         private readonly MyDBContext _dbContext;
         
         public OrderService(MyDBContext dbContext)
         {
             _dbContext = dbContext;
         }
         
         public Order[] GetActiveOrders()
         {
             var orders = _dbContext.Orders.Where(x=>x.Status == 'Active').ToArray()
             return orders;
         }
         
         #region Dispose
         public void Dispose()
         {
              Dispose(true);
              GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
         }
    
         protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
         {
              if (_disposed)
                  return;

              if (disposing)
              {
                  if (_dbContext != null)
                  {
                      _dbContext.Dispose();
                  }

                  // Free any other managed objects here.                    
              }

              // Free any unmanaged objects here.
              _disposed = true;
          }
      }
```

I am assuming under the hood, the `DbContext` is still using `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` to connect to the database.

I want to know when does EF Core close the `SqlConnection`? Does it close the connection as soon as it's done executing the query (like how we do in classic ADO) or when the `DbContext` is disposed?

So in the example above, will it dispose the connection before returning `Orders` from the `GetActiveOrders()` method or when the `OrderService` is disposed by the DI container?

Comment: Generally service should not dispose resources which it does not own, i.e. any dependency injected via ctor.

Answer (score 3):

Side note: you shouldn't dispose something you don't own, which is the case with DI injected `DbContext` (and any injected object).

But to answer you concrete question. I can't find documentation to link to, but as soon as you

- don't provide pre allocated `DbConnection` object via `DbContextOptions`
- don't manually open connection via `.Database.OpenConnection` method
- don't open explicit transactions via `Database.BeginTransaction` method

i.e. do not take some connection management by yourself (in which case you are responsible for closing/disposing), EF Core opens connection only when needed and closes it immediately after that.

When needed means opening a transaction during the `SaveChanges` until it gets commit or rolled back. Or when executing `DbReader` returning query until the returned reader is consumed or cancelled. In other words, exactly how you would do it with classic ADO.NET. And yes, behind the scenes it uses ADO.NET (at least for relational databases).

Some additional info here [Do I need to close the DbConnection manually when using ambient transactions with EF Core 2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239326/do-i-need-to-close-the-dbconnection-manually-when-using-ambient-transactions-wit/51252329#51252329) and [Using EF Core to invoke stored procedure and closing connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57283317/using-ef-core-to-invoke-stored-procedure-and-closing-connection/57287020#57287020). Also [Connection Resiliency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency) and [How queries work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works) documentation topics.

Comment: So connection should get disposed before GetActiveOrders() returns back to caller?

Comment: In your example, it will be opened at the time `ToArray` method invokes `GetEnumerator().MoveNext()` (the query execution point) of the passed `IQueryable`. And will close it immediately after `ToArray()` completes (finishing consuming the returned `DbReader`). What about disposing, I'm not sure, for sure it will be closed, which should return the physical connection to the pool.

Comment: EF Core internal code is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57283317/using-ef-core-to-invoke-stored-procedure-and-closing-connection/57287020#57287020, but with more checks and do not call close until the open reader is closed in case of `ExecuteReader`. So no `Dispose`, but it's not needed.

Comment: Microsoft [states clearly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/) that _It is very important to dispose the DbContext after use_.